# Is my approach to cutting body fat good?

Tags: weight-loss, strength, cardio, muscle-mass, burn-fat

I've researched and understood that in order to cut my fat, I need to be in a caloric deficit of around 500 calories, do lots of cardiovascular exercise to lose fat, and do a moderate amount of strength training to maintain my muscle (modify intensity of strength training when you hit plateaus), eat good amount of protein, follow your cutting macronutrients, track your progress, update the caloric deficit, update your macronutrients, and get good sleep.

So if I'm at my cutting phase, is this a good exercise routine throughout the week?

**Day 1: Upper Body + Cardio**

*Upper Body Strength:*

- Push-Ups: 3 sets of 12 reps
- Dumbbell Rows: 3 sets of 12 reps per arm
- Dumbbell Bench Press: 3 sets of 12 reps
- Bicep Curls: 3 sets of 12 reps
- Tricep Dips: 3 sets of 12 reps
- Cardio on a treadmill (45 minutes)

**Day 2: Lower Body + Cardio**

*Lower Body Strength:*

- Squats: 3 sets of 15 reps
- Lunges: 3 sets of 12 reps per leg
- Leg Press Machine: 3 sets of 12 reps
- Calf Raises: 3 sets of 15 reps
- Cardio on a treadmill (45 minutes)

---

**Day 3: Core + Cardio**

*Core Strength:*

- Plank: 3 sets, hold for 1 minute each
- Russian Twists: 3 sets of 20 reps
- Bicycle Crunches: 3 sets of 20 reps
- Cardio on a treadmill(45 minutes)

**Day 4: Upper Body + Cardio**

*Upper Body Strength:*

- Pull-Ups or Lat Pulldowns: 3 sets of 12 reps
- Dumbbell Shoulder Press: 3 sets of 12 reps
- Dumbbell Flies: 3 sets of 12 reps
- Hammer Curls: 3 sets of 12 reps
- Skull Crushers: 3 sets of 12 reps
- Cardio on a treadmill (45 minutes)

**Day 5: Lower Body + Cardio**

*Lower Body Strength:*

- Deadlifts: 3 sets of 12 reps
- Leg Curls: 3 sets of 12 reps
- Bulgarian Split Squats: 3 sets of 12 reps per leg
- Seated Calf Raises: 3 sets of 15 reps
- Cardio on a treadmill (45 minutes)

**Day 6: Core + Cardio**

*Core Strength:*

- Hanging Leg Raises: 3 sets of 12 reps
- Plank Twists: 3 sets of 20 reps (10 per side)
- Reverse Crunches: 3 sets of 15 reps
- Cardio on a treadmill (45 minutes)

**Day 7: Rest or Light Activity**

Is my understanding of cutting body fat and my workout schedule good?

Comment: Some explanation about the intensity of your cardio would be helpful. There’s a big difference between an easy 45 minute walk and running a 10k.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov I will alternate through intensities throughout the cardio session. I'll do high intensity for a minute, then a moderate intensity (lightly jogging or walking) for 1.5 minutes to rest. I'll be doing this for the entirety of the cardio session.

Comment: Rep range way too high

Comment: @ReineAbstraktion that rep range is perfect. It's at the top end of the standard rep range for bodybuilding, but if the main goal is fat loss, then higher reps is preferable.

Comment: @ReineAbstraktion Also, higher reps and lower loads are not *much* worse even for building 1RM and hypertrophy. Thus, "reps way too high" does not exist, only "the sets are way too easy to do for this particular person at that particular time". Real science over bro science here, please.